# using the Instagram API, can i display get all posts from a specific location?

Tags: php, instagram

Hi Instagram Developers,
I'd like to get a feed of all instagram posts of our location (guests who post images from their stay with us). Unfortunately, with the API I can't get any other posts than my own users, which is clearly not what i want... is there any way to do that?

integration using php

Thanks for any help
flo

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This site is designed for users like yourself to ask questions relating to specific problems you're having with code that you've written, so that we can help you to fix it. If you haven't written anything yet, please go and give it a go and come back if you have problems and can't find any help online already. Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the Instagram API using the location ID of your business, like this: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/{location-id}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

This will return the most recent posts for your location.

If you don't know your location ID, it's the number at the end of the URL for your location page on Instagram e.g. https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/222206243/.

See their documentation for more info on what is included:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/